# Create a front page template and separate page for posts?

Tags: homepage, blog, frontpage, blog-page

I'm building a WordPress theme. I need two type of pages, one is home page which will display on www.example.com. I also need a list of all my posts on www.example.com/blog/, but I need both in one WordPress theme.

Is there the right way to use home.php or front-page.php?

If no then please suggest me the right way to solve my problem. If yes then please suggest me how can I see all my blog post list on www.example.com/blog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [WordPress Reading settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen) for your posts page named blog and [create a static front-page.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) file for your front page in your theme.